# error when generating gridview

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server

hye, i'm having a problem when i'm inserting data in textbox.the problem is when i'm searching for data 10/10/2010, it work perfectly but when i try to search other date (eg 25/11/2013), i would get error The conversion of a varchar data type to a datetime data type resulted in an out-of-range value.  the error occur at "gridmaxdata.DataBind();"

```
protected void searchdata_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    data();
    byday2();
}

public void data()
{
    if (Dayrange.Checked == true)
    {
        startdate = DateTime.ParseExact(txtStart1.Text, "dd/MM/yyyy", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
        enddate = DateTime.ParseExact(txtEnd1.Text, "dd/MM/yyyy", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
        //starttime = DateTime.ParseExact(txtStart1.Text, "HH:mm:ss", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
        //endtime = DateTime.ParseExact(txtStart1.Text, "HH:mm:ss", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
        Label1.Text = startdate.ToShortDateString();
        Label2.Text = enddate.ToShortDateString();
    }
    if (Byday.Checked == true)
    {
        startdate = DateTime.ParseExact(txtStart1.Text, "dd/MM/yyyy", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
        enddate = startdate.AddDays(1);
        //starttime = DateTime.ParseExact(txtStart1.Text, "HH:mm:ss", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
        //endtime = DateTime.ParseExact(txtStart1.Text, "HH:mm:ss", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
        Label1.Text = startdate.ToShortDateString();
        Label2.Text = enddate.ToShortDateString();
    }

}

public void byday2()
{

    if (Byday.Checked == true)
    {
        if (Maxdata.Checked == true)
        {
            //tablemax.hidden = true;
            lblmaxdata.Visible = true;
            lblmaxdata.Text = "Highest Data";
            // ConnectionString to NorthWind Database.
            string connectionString = "Data Source=.\\SQLEXPRESS;AttachDbFilename=C:\\Users\\shafiq\\Desktop\\history\\App_Data\\Radiation.mdf;Integrated Security=True;User Instance=True";

            // Create SQLDataSource.
            SqlDataSource sqlDataSource = new SqlDataSource();
            sqlDataSource.ID = "SqlDataSource123";
            this.Page.Controls.Add(sqlDataSource);

            // Bind ConnectionString to SQLDataSource.
            sqlDataSource.ConnectionString = connectionString;
            // Retrieve records with only 5 Columns from Employees table of NorthWind Database.
            sqlDataSource.SelectCommand = "SELECT [date], [data] FROM [loc1] WHERE (([data] >= '2') AND ([date] >= '" + Convert.ToDateTime(startdate).ToString("dd/MM/yyyy") + "') AND ([date] < '" + Convert.ToDateTime(enddate).ToString("dd/MM/yyyy") + "')) ORDER BY [data] DESC, [date] DESC";

            // Bind SQLDataSource to GridView after retrieving the records.
            gridmaxdata.DataSource = sqlDataSource;
            gridmaxdata.DataBind();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

better to use parameters

```
sqlDataSource.SelectCommand = "SELECT [date], [data] FROM [loc1] WHERE (([data] >= '2') AND ([date] >= @startdate) AND ([date] < @enddate)) ORDER BY [data] DESC, [date] DESC";
sqlDataSource.SelectCommand.Parameters.AddwithValue("@startdate",startdate);
sqlDataSource.SelectCommand.Parameters.AddwithValue("@enddate",enddate);
```

Comment: thanks, its working now... i have also tried this code and it is working.

Comment: thanks, it working now. I just notice that it could also work like this.

sqlDataSource.SelectCommand = "SELECT [date], [data] FROM [loc1] WHERE (([date] >= '" + startdate.ToLongDateString() + "') AND ([date] < '" + enddate.ToLongDateString() + "')) ORDER BY [data] DESC, [date] DESC";

Comment: never use inline SQL with parameters, your code id widely open for sql injection attacks, always try to use parameters

Answer (score 0):

it is because in the date 25/11/2013, 25 gets as month, 11 gets as date and 2013 gets as year. hence there is no month 25. then it will throw an exception.
you can try this approach `convert(varchar, startdate, 103)` 
for more information http://anubhavg.wordpress.com/2009/06/11/how-to-format-datetime-date-in-sql-server-2005/

Comment: but OP is using `dd/MM/yyyy` custom format right so why it is still treating date as month. any particular statement?

Comment: it is because IFormatProvider or cultue. have to look at http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w2sa9yss%28v=vs.110%29.aspx,http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zdtaw1bw%28v=vs.110%29.aspx,